# How to put numbers in variables?

Tags: dos, tasm, x86-16

How do I enable a user to put some number (values) in variables A, B and C? I don't know to start writing.

```
stk segment stack
            db      256 dup ('?')   ;segment steka
    stk ends
    ;------------------------------------------------------
    code    segment para public 'code'    
        assume cs:code,ss:stk
        A db ?
        B db ?
        C db
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is full code ,and this program print error(greska) if A + B + C is greather than 9

```
data segment
        poruka1 db 'Unesi,write A: ', '$'
        poruka2 db 'Unesi B: ', '$'
        poruka3 db 'Unesi C: ', '$'
        greska db 'Greska', '$'
        A db 0
        B db 0
        C db 0
        nr db 13, 10, '$'
    data ends

    stk segment stack
        db 256 dup (?)

    stk ends

    code segment
        assume cs: code, ds: data, ss: stk
    main:

        mov ax, data
        mov ds, ax

        mov ah, 09h
        lea dx, poruka1
        int 21h

        mov ah, 01h ; u al ide cifra
        int 21h
        mov dl, al
        sub dl, 30h
        mov A, dl

        mov ah, 09h
        lea dx, nr
        int 21h

        mov ah, 09h
        lea dx, poruka2
        int 21h

        mov ah, 01h ; u al ide cifra
        int 21h
        mov dl, al
        sub dl, 30h
        mov B, dl

        mov ah, 09h
        lea dx, nr
        int 21h

        mov ah, 09h
        lea dx, poruka3
        int 21h

        mov ah, 01h ; u al ide cifra
        int 21h
        mov dl, al
        sub dl, 30h
        mov C, dl

        xor bx, bx
        mov bl, A
        add bl, B
        add bl, C

        cmp bl, 9h
        jg odje

        mov ah, 09h
        lea dx, nr
        int 21h

        mov ah, 02h
        mov dl, bl
        add dl, 30h
        int 21h

        jmp kraj

        odje:

        mov ah, 09h
        lea dx, nr
        int 21h

        mov ah, 09h
        lea dx, greska
        int 21h

        kraj:
        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h

    code ends
    end main
```